# ScrollView State Not Saved in KitKat and Earlier

Tags: android

The scroll state of an item on a view pager is not getting saved and restored on android KitKat and older devices (I've tested API 15,17,19,22,23 at this point)

The scroll view is in a fragment inside another fragment with a view pager.

The view pager adapter is a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

When the pager adapter saves the state, it calls `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager#saveFragmentInstanceState`.

From there we end up in `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl#saveFragmentViewState` but a call to `ScrollView#saveHierarchyState` doesn't add a saved state to the bundle like it does on newer devices. Specifically the newer devices add an instance of `android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.SavedState` (That's what the debugger says anyhow, the code suggests it would be a `android.widget.ScrollView.SavedState` whereas the older API devices add `android.view.AbsSavedState#EMPTY_STATE`

```
void saveFragmentViewState(Fragment f) { //f is my fragment
    if (f.mInnerView == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (mStateArray == null) {
        mStateArray = new SparseArray<Parcelable>();
    } else {
        mStateArray.clear();
    }
    // f.mInnerView is a ScrollView
    f.mInnerView.saveHierarchyState(mStateArray); //should save state here 
    if (mStateArray.size() > 0) {
        f.mSavedViewState = mStateArray;
        mStateArray = null;
    }
}
```

Further investigation of what should be happening lead me to `android.widget.ScrollView#onSaveInstanceState` which actually saves the scroll position into `android.widget.ScrollView.SavedState#scrollPosition`

Answer (score 0):

When I diffed `ScrollView.java` between android API 23 and 19, I found that newer versions had indeed added code which saves and restores this state.

I discovered that the support library widget, [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html), was the easiest solution as it saves scroll state properly. As the linked documentation states, it doesn't actually need to be *nested* as the same class can be the parent or nested child. One important change I needed to make was to include the scrollbars which aren't there by default for some reason with this class.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.FragmentOne">
```